# как сделать так, чтобы функция от вектора возвращала вектор Python

Tags: python

Я записываю функцию в следующем виде:

```
def error(w_0, w_1):
    return (scipy.sum((y - (w_0 + x*w_1))**2))
```

где x и y - это вектора. Если подавать функции числа в качестве аргумента, то всё хорошо. Но если подавать два вектора, чтобы он вычислял значение функции на векторах поэлементно, то он начинает видимо перемножать вектора, а я хочу чтобы возвращался тоже вектор.

Как это можно сделать?

*P.S. В конечном итоге я хочу нарисовать трехмерный график этой функции.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать векторизовать функцию при помощи `scipy.vectorize`, например вот так:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7])

@sp.vectorize
def error(w_0, w_1):
    return sp.sum((y - (w_0 + x * w_1)) ** 2)

w0 = [1, 2, 3]
w1 = [3, 2, 1]

print(error(w0, w1))
```

В результате получите:

```
[56 14  0]
```

Comment: когда я хочу подать на вход функции вектора, чтобы построить график, он начинает x вектор  умножать на w_o как вектор , а мне нужно для построения, чтобы возвращался массив, где на нулевом месте `sp.sum((y - (w_0[1] + x * w_1[0])) ** 2)` и т.д.

Comment: Изменил свой ответ, надеюсь я вас правильно понял.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите строить трехмерный график, то вам нужно воспользоваться функцией meshgrid для генерации сетки.

Например,

```
import numpy
w0 = numpy.arange(-10, 10, 0.05)
w1 = numpy.arange(-10, 10, 0.05)
w0_grid, w1_grid = numpy.meshgrid(w0, w1)
z = error(w0_grid, w1_grid)
```

В результате w0_grid, w1_grid и z будут двумерными векторами.